# Multiple Variables in Directory PHP

Tags: php

Easy question today, but I'm coming up nile on searching. I've tried a few PHP escape sequences but can't seem to get it right.

What I am trying to do is use 2 variables from POST to run a script in a directory they define on the backend.

Example:

```php
<?php
    $first= $_POST['first'];
    $second= $_POST['second'];
    $test=file('/this/then/' . $first . '/' . $second . '.this.txt'); 
?>
```

Desired actual directory would be for example:

```
/this/then/first/second.this.txt
```

What is the correct method for passing these two POST variables like this?

Comment: you code is correct. http://ideone.com/pl1XiU

Comment: I must have a mistake somewhere else....hmm...thanks for checking it out.

Comment: Looks alright to me too. `var_dump($_POST)` and see if they're coming across okay. There may be an issue with your form (or whatever you're using to post to this script.)

Comment: Usually good step is print generated file path

Comment: A common cause of missing post parameters is un-named or mis-named form inputs.

Comment: I am getting the form data and I printed the generated file path and it is correct - my mistake is elsewhere. Probably on the backend with the script it is firing. I'll keep digging. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Comment: You should escape your input before using it, maybe `escapeshellarg` might be useful here